# Word 2010 vba to find and go to the most recent tracked changes

Tags: vba, ms-word, change-tracking

I have a macro that finds all tracked changes made in the last day and highlights them.

```
Sub HilightNewChanges()

'''''''''''''
' Finds tracked changes made in the last day, and
' highlights them (without tracking the highlighting)
'''''''''''''

Dim bTrackingAsWas As Boolean
    bTrackingAsWas = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = True

  Dim aRev As Revision
  For Each aRev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    If aRev.Date > Now() - 1 Then
      aRev.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
      Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End If
  Next aRev

    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = bTrackingAsWas
    ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = True

End Sub
```

I need to alter this so it, instead of highlighting all of them, will step through the doc to each one so I can review just the new changes. I've tried replacing the two lines in the If with

```
    aRev.Range.GoTo What:=aRev
```

but I get a "bad parameter" error. I've used GoTo in other macros, but only with bookmarks. Do I need to use bookmarks again to get what I need here? How do I build the If or Loop so it stops after each one?

Answer (score 0):

[`Range.GoTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835184(v=office.15).aspx) is used for getting a range of a particular type. The `What` parameter has to be one of a particular set of constants, such as `wdGoToLine`.

Instead, you can select the start of the range you've already got:

```
aRev.Range.Select
Selection.Collapse
```

To make it stop after each one, the easiest way would be to rework it to just find the next matching revision after the current insertion point instead of all of them at once. If you assign a hotkey to the macro then it will be easy to keep running it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and help! For my current document, the deadline is too close to work on this any more; I'm making do by using Find to jump to highlighted text.